Azure Marketplace SaaS Accelerator Installation Error: Unauthorized to Perform Action on Key Vault
I am trying to install the Azure Marketplace SaaS Accelerator using Azure Cloud Shell, following the installation instructions provided in the GitHub repository.
However, I encounter errors when running the installation script. The specific errors are related to unauthorized actions on the Key Vault. Here are the error messages I receive:

The script fails at these points in the Deploy.ps1 file:

Line 361
Line 377
Line 389


It seems that the caller (Azure CLI user) does not have the required permissions to set secrets in the Key Vault configured with RBAC.
Steps I have taken:

Tried to get the Object ID of the currently logged-in user:
az account show --query user.name -o tsv


Attempted to retrieve the Object ID using the email returned:
az ad user list --filter "userPrincipalName eq 'me@myemail.com'" --query "[].{id:objectId}" -o tsv


Verified Azure CLI login and retrieved account details:
az account show



Questions:

How can I correctly retrieve the Object ID for my logged-in user in Azure Cloud Shell?
How can I ensure my user has the necessary permissions to set secrets in the Key Vault?
Is there a way to handle this RBAC issue directly within the deployment script?

Any guidance or steps to resolve this authorization issue would be greatly appreciated!
Attachments:

Error screenshots and more detailed information on the setup.

Thank you!

Error 1

Error 2

Error 3



How can I correctly retrieve the Object ID for my logged-in user in Azure Cloud Shell?

You can make use of below CLI command to retrieve Object ID of logged-in user in Azure Cloud Shell:
az ad signed-in-user show --query id -o tsv

Response:


How can I ensure my user has the necessary permissions to set secrets in the Key Vault?

Note that, running below command will create key vault with Access configuration set to RBAC access by default:
az keyvault create --name kvname --resource-group rgname


In that case, generic roles like Owner or Contributor won't work to set secrets in key vault and throws error like this:
az keyvault secret set --vault-name kvname --name secretname --value="secretvalue"

Response:

To resolve the error, the signed-in user must either have "Key Vault Administrator" or "Key Vault Secrets Officer" role to set secrets.
You can make use of this command to assign required RBAC role to signed-in user:
az role assignment create --assignee "userObjID" --role "Key Vault Administrator" --scope "/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/rgName/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/kvname"

Response:

When I ran the command again after assigning role to signed-in user, secrets created successfully as below:
az keyvault secret set --vault-name kvname --name secretname --value="secretvalue"

Response:


Is there a way to handle this RBAC issue directly within the deployment script?

Alternatively, you can modify this command by disabling RBAC access that creates Azure key vault with Vault access:
az keyvault create --name kvname --resource-group rgname --enable-rbac-authorization false


Replace this line 360 with below modified command that resolves all 3 mentioned deployment errors related to key vault.
az keyvault create --name $KeyVault --resource-group $ResourceGroupForDeployment --enable-rbac-authorization false --output $azCliOutput


Thanks so much for the response, I'll give this a try today.

I think you are saying that we need to do a PR as the script is broken? And that I need to update line 360 to not use the RBAC. So, then, will the script work and the tutorial work after making this change? Also i have to run locally given that I have to make this change and not in the Azure CLI.

Hi Sridevi, I've been unable to run this locally on PowerShell 5.1 and 7.4.2. :-(

Had to add:
$userObjID = az ad signed-in-user show --query id -o tsv
az role assignment create --assignee $userObjID --role "Key Vault Administrator" --scope "/subscriptions/$AzureSubscriptionID/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupForDeployment/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/$KeyVault"

and also  --enable-rbac-authorization false and then it worked, looks like the script is broke. Lmk if I need to do a quick PR.

We can access key vault with either access control or with vault access policies. But you can't use both at once. If you prefer to go with RBAC access, you can add Key Vault Administrator role to users and web apps involved in that deployment without creating any access policies.

Instead of all this, you can just replace  line 360 in the deployment script adding  --enable-rbac-authorization false to make whole deployment work without need of assigning RBAC roles.

When you run the deployment script in Azure Cloud Shell adding --enable-rbac-authorization false, it will automatically add vault access policies to signed in user.

But when you run this script in local Powershell, you need to add access policies to signed in user manually after creating key vault with --enable-rbac-authorization false
